# How to setHint in TextInputLayout programmatically in android?

Tags: android, android-design-library, android-textinputlayout

Currently, I use TextInputLayout ([See](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html)) which the hint can float to the top when control is focused. It works well but I cannot setHint to it programmatically when I click on a button.

Here is what I did.

> editText1.setHint("Input username");

This is my xml code

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="20dp">

        <EditText
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:id="@+id/user_field"
           android:hint="Enter your User-ID or username"
           android:singleLine="true"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

This is control before click button.

[image]

After click button

[image]

**It should change the small red text to Input username.**

Thank for any helps.

Comment: Thank @MikeM., I will look that the thread.

Comment: @MikeM. Correct, It work now. I should marked my question duplicate. But why I cannot use the edittext inside of the TextInputLayout tag to set the hint? In xml, when I can set hint in editText and it work but in code cannot. I have to use from the main tag.

Comment: `TextInputLayout` will grab the hint itself from the `EditText` when it's first initialized - i.e., when your layout is loaded - but after that, you need to set the hint on the `TextInputLayout` directly.